# Using forms to interact with models that contain foreign keys

Tags: django, django-forms

So I'm trying to do something really simple but I've been trying for what seems like ages and simply can't find the answer by myself.

I'm trying to create a form to add a devicetype. In that form there's supposed to be a dropdown menu of existing vendors in the database. The only problem is that I can't seem to display the name of the vendor in the form. Instead it shows the instance name. "Vendors object(1)", "Vendors object(2)". How do I change it to display the name?

here are my models:

```
class Vendors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class DeviceTypes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendors, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

And this is my form:

```
class AddDeviceTypeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form to add a devicetype to database
    """
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceTypes
        fields = ['name', 'vendor']
```

This is my view:

```
def addDeviceType(request):
    """
    view shows and processes form to add a device type
    """
    form = AddDeviceTypeForm()
    args = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'cmdb/addDeviceType.html', args)
```

And I'm displaying the form with:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

To display vendor name you need to add [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#str) method to vendor model:

```
class Vendors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Thanks! Like I thought this should be simple.